# re.sub emptying list

Tags: python, regex

```
def process_dialect_translation_rules():

    # Read in lines from the text file specified in sys.argv[1], stripping away
    # excess whitespace and discarding comments (lines that start with '##').
    f_lines = [line.strip() for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r').readlines()]
    f_lines = filter(lambda line: not re.match(r'##', line), f_lines)

    # Remove any occurances of the pattern '\s*<=>\s*'. This leaves us with a 
    # list of lists. Each 2nd level list has two elements: the value to be 
    # translated from and the value to be translated to. Use the sub function
    # from the re module to get rid of those pesky asterisks.
    f_lines = [re.split(r'\s*<=>\s*', line) for line in f_lines]
    f_lines = [re.sub(r'"', '', elem) for elem in line for line in f_lines]
```

This function should take the lines from a file and perform some operations on the lines, such as removing any lines that begin with `##`. Another operation that I wish to perform is to remove the quotation marks around the words in the line. However, when the final line of this script runs, `f_lines` becomes an empty lines. What happened?

Requested lines of original file:

```
##  English-Geek Reversible Translation File #1
##   (Moderate Geek)
##  Created by Todd WAreham, October 2009

"TV show"    <=> "STAR TREK"
"food"       <=> "pizza"
"drink"      <=> "Red Bull"
"computer"   <=> "TRS 80"
"girlfriend" <=> "significant other"
```

Comment: Could you provide a few lines of the original file for us to test?

Comment: Done. The goal here is to strip the quotation marks from the strings and create a dictionary mapping the first value to the second value. I think I have everything else working, but stripping the quotes has proved troublesome.  
  
EDIT: I also just tried using f_lines[elem.strip('"') for elem in line for line in f_lines], but this too erased the entire list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, multiple `for` loops in a list comprehension are handled *from left to right*, not from right to left, so your last expression should read:

```
[re.sub(r'"', '', elem) for line in f_lines for elem in line]
```

It doesn't lead to an error as it is, since list comprehensions leak the loop variable, so `line` is still in scope from the previous expression. If that `line` then is an empty string you get an empty list as result.

Comment: @jmau5 - In case you need the `dict` bit of your goal, I posted as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you have chosen an over-complicated way of doing things, and come unstuck. Use the simplest tool that will get the job done. You don't need filter, map, lambda, readlines, and all of those list comprehensions (one will do). Using re.match instead of startswith is overkill. So is using re.sub where str.replace would do the job.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue # empty line
        if line.startswith('##'): continue # comment line
        parts = line.split('<=>')
        assert len(parts) == 2 # or print an error message ...
        key, value = [part.strip('" ') for part in parts]
        assert key not in d # or print an error message ...
        d[key] = value
```

Bonus extra: You get to check for dodgy lines and duplicate keys.

Comment: I agree that it is over-complicated, but my professor asked us to "make extensive use of the re module". :)

Comment: The re module is only about 40% of the bloat.

Comment: You missed out on one obfuscation opportunity: instead of `line.strip()`, use `re.sub(r'^\s*(.*?)\s*\Z', r'\1', line)`

Comment: @jmau5 - I understand you are new on SO, so I hope you don't mind if I point out three things for you: (1) if it is homework, tag you question with that word (I did it for you now). It is OK to ask help on assignments, but if we know, we will probably help you in a way that maximise your learning, with more comments, etc... (2) If answers to your question brings additional value (= new useful information), it is good praxis to upvote them - regardless of if you used them or not: reputation is what keeps SO going! (3) Best luck with your assignment! :)

Comment: @mac - Will do from now on. The only problem is that I can't actually upvote yet. ;)